# Plot multiple series using array data

Tags: excel, vba, plot

I'm trying to plot three series on a chart table from arrays.

ct is a chart table that is already created. The one-dimensional arrays A, B, C, x have the same length, as well as the same LBound and UBound.

```
Dim sr As Series
For Each sr In ct.SeriesCollection
    sr.Delete
Next

With ct.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "A"
    .Values = a
    .XValues = x
End With

With ct.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "B"
    .Values = b
    .XValues = x
End With

With ct.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .Name = "C"
    .Values = c
    .XValues = x
End With
```

However, there are no bars or lines on the graph after I run the macro. I see only the tags "A", "B", "C" on the right side on the graph.

Comment: Can you extend your code to the part where you define `a`,`b`,`c`,`x` arrays ?

Comment: Sounds like there may be no data in the array.  If you hard code the array does it plot?  i.e.  `.Values = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`

Comment: The part of the code where I get a,b,c is quite long and a little bit complex. However, I use Debug.Print to print the data in a,b,c so I am sure I get the right numbers (I also check TypeName of elements in the arrays is double).

Comment: If I hard code the array to be 1,2,3..., there is still no data on the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NewSeries empties the existing data in SeriesCollection every time.  It works after I put those three NewSeries together before filling in    the data.

```
With ct.SeriesCollection
    .NewSeries
    .NewSeries
    .NewSeries

    .Item(1).Name = "A"
    .Item(1).Values = a
    .Item(1).XValues = x

    .Item(2).Name = "B"
    .Item(2).Values = b
    .Item(2).XValues = x

    .Item(3).Name = "C"
    .Item(3).Values = c
    .Item(3).XValues = x
End With
```